# Green's Theorem with respect to a given polar region.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, problem-solving, polar-coordinates

> Using Green's Theorem, compute the counterclockwise circulation $I$ of
>   $\vec{F}=\langle-\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\rangle$ around the
>   region defined by the polar coordinate inequalities $7 \leq r \leq 8$
>   and $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$.

My inclination is to approach as follows:
$$
\\ \displaystyle
\\ Q =  \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \implies Q_x = \dfrac{ x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\\ P = -\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \implies P_y = \dfrac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\\ 
\\ 
\\ x = r\cos{\theta}
\\ y = r\sin{\theta}
\\ \implies \vec{F} = \langle -r, r \rangle
\\ \implies I = \int\int_R \left(Q_x-P_y\right) \mathrm{d}A = \int_0^\pi \int_7^8 \frac{r^2(\cos{\theta}+\sin{\theta})}{r}\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta
\\ \implies I = \int_0^\pi (\cos{\theta} + \sin{\theta}) \ \mathrm{d}\theta \cdot \int_7^8 r \ \mathrm{d}r
$$
Evaluate and find $I = -15$.

Is this effective, valid, both, or neither?

Comment: the only issue i see is that when you convert to polar coordinates it should be $\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta)$ instead of $\cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta)$.

Comment: After Nathan's correction, don't forget to also change the sign of the result: $I = 15$. Other than that, I see no mistake and everything is fine.